# Missing Method in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Have this annoying problem with my CakePHP

```
Missing Method in GamesReviewsController
```

Error: The action deadspace2.html is not defined in controller GamesReviewsController
Error: Create GamesReviewsController::deadspace2.html() in file: app/controllers/games_reviews_controller.php.

What could be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure Router::parseExtensions in cake routes config allows html extension. So you must have following string:

```
Router::parseExtensions('xml','csv','txt','pdf', 'html')
```

in your /app/config/routes.php